# Login button does not work with enter key in Bootstrap Template

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

You can log in clicking on the button but not with the Enter Key.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LoginButton" CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right
TheLinkButton" CommandName="Login" meta:resourcekey="LinkButton1Resource1" TabIndex="1" 
ValidationGroup="1" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: You're using a LinkButton which will render as link (<a>). You have to change to a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this to `Page_Load`:

```
LinkButton button = (Login1.FindControl("LoginButton") as LinkButton);
form1.DefaultButton = button.UniqueID;
```

It's working.